# Error while running jenkins build

Tags: jenkins, artifactory

I am getting below error while running my build. The build is triggering other builds also and creating and deploying RPMS.

Artifactory plugin version is 2.10.3

```
FATAL: org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.ArtifactoryClientConfiguration.setConnectionRetries(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.ArtifactoryClientConfiguration.setConnectionRetries(Ljava/lang/Integer;)V
    at org.jfrog.hudson.util.ExtractorUtils.setRetryParams(ExtractorUtils.java:400)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.util.ExtractorUtils.setPublisherInfo(ExtractorUtils.java:313)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.util.ExtractorUtils.getArtifactoryClientConfiguration(ExtractorUtils.java:155)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.util.ExtractorUtils.addBuilderInfoArguments(ExtractorUtils.java:141)
    at org.jfrog.hudson.maven3.extractor.MavenExtractorEnvironment.buildEnvVars(MavenExtractorEnvironment.java:139)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractBuild.java:931)
    at hudson.maven.AbstractMavenBuild.getEnvironment(AbstractMavenBuild.java:56)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.getEnvironment(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:169)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.doRun(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:544)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please clear Jenkins cache and update
Artifactory-Jenkins-Plugin to the latest version v2.10.4.